# OSGI JAX-WS Client On WebSphere Application Server

Tags: osgi, jax-ws, websphere-8

I am trying to implement an OSGI based JAX-WS WebService client on WebSphere Application Server(8.5.5). I created a web project in my RAD (Rational Application Developer) workbench and added the programming model as osgi.
After that I tried to create the webservice client from the available wsdl.
But I am getting the following error **`" The IBM WebSphere JAX-WS Web service runtime does not support Client projects with the OSGi Bundle facet."`**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JAX-WS on WebSphere Application Server traditional (i.e. not the Liberty Profile)?  If so, then traditional does not support JAX-WS in OSGi Applications.  The Liberty profile does support JAX-WS.

If not, then this could be a tools check that's no longer valid.  I know the tools used to prevent you doing this when JAX-WS was not supported on traditional or Liberty.  You could try using the latest WebSphere Developer tools from the Ecilpse Marketplace or https://wasdev.net/repo to create a simple test project to see if you hit the same problem.

I hope this helps.

Regards, Graham.